# Issue with MultipartFile Upload From React/Node

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I have the following JAVA controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/data/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    void uploadData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        logger.info("Received File for Ingestion");
        dataUploadService.processData(file.getInputStream());
    }
```

Node server side code:

```
serviceCall(serviceCallRequestData, request, finalResponse) {
        logger.info('Making remote request: ' + JSON.stringify(serviceCallRequestData));

        let file = request.files['file']; // file: Object {name: "sample_aspect_review_upload.csv", encoding: "7bit", mimetype: "text/csv", mv: }
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', Buffer.from(file.data));

        fetch(serviceCallRequestData.url, {
            method: serviceCallRequestData.requestObject.method,
            headers: serviceCallRequestData.requestObject.headers,
            body: formData
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                logger.error(`Error while making http call requestData: ${JSON.stringify(serviceCallRequestData)}`);
                finalResponse.status(500).send('Internal server error');
                return;
            }

            return response.json();
        }).then((json) => {
            logger.info(`Returning response for aspect-review-file-upload: ${JSON.stringify(json)}`);
            finalResponse.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(json));
        }).catch((e) => {
            logger.error(`Error while making http call requestData: ${JSON.stringify(serviceCallRequestData)} error: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
            finalResponse.status(500).send('Internal server error');
        });
    }
```

Trying to upload a csv file like:

```
"product_id","review_id","aspect_id","rating","confidence_score","indices"
"pid","rid","aid",1,0.851955,"[{\"s\":0,\"e\":114,\"highlights\":[39,68]}]"
```

The upload happens easily from POSTMAN. See the below screenshot:
[image]

Getting an error in JAVA: **Received Unknown exception org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present**
when I am not passing contentType header from React.

Getting an error in JAVA: **org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found** when I am passing contentType header from React as 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'

The same Node server side code for a JAVA dropwizard controller as:

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail
    ) throws IOException {
        logger.debug("Request to upload data file-name: {}", fileDetail.getName());

        dataUploadService.processData(inputStream);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

works correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What headers are you sending from node server? Did you include the `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` header?

Comment: @TarunLalwani: I have clearly mentioned the errors that I am getting when sending data with `"Content-Type"` header

Comment: I see the current answer as changes required on your back-end side, are you looking for a fix to the front-end code to make it work or are you evaluating changing the backend also as an option?

Comment: @TarunLalwani: Would prefer a frontend change, as there is no issue with the API when I hit it from POSTMAN.

Comment: Can you put a `socat` in between your FE and BE and compare the two requests? http://tarunlalwani.com/post/how-to-debug-nginx-reverse-proxy-issues-php-fpm-gunicorn-uwsgi/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From curl of postman you can see the following command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -F "file=@\"/pathto/sample.csv\";type=text/csv;filename=\"sample.csv\"" 'http://localhost:8080/data/upload'
```

So i tried adding `type=text/csv;filename=\"sample.csv\"` in the form-data
so this should work:

```
    let file = request.files['file'];
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", Buffer.from(file.data), {
        filename: file.name,
        contentType: file.mimetype,
    });

    fetch(serviceCallRequestData.url, {
        method: serviceCallRequestData.requestObject.method,
        headers: serviceCallRequestData.requestObject.headers,
        body: formData
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {}
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Few speculations:

1. In your REST endpoint definition you specify file to be request parameter which is used to extract parameters from the URI itself, while multipart file upload sits within the body of the POST request.

   Add `consumes={}` and instead of `@RequestParam` you can use `@RequestBody` annotation:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/data/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST,
     consumes = {"multipart/mixed", "multipart/form-data"}
   )
   void uploadData(@RequestBody MultipartFile file) //body will be the whole JSON payload
   ```

   OR even better use `@RequestPart` where you can name the element:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/data/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST,
     consumes = {"multipart/mixed", "multipart/form-data"}
   )
   void uploadData(@RequestPart (value="file") MultipartFile file) //gets file from JSON
   ```
2. Provide options to `FormData`:

   ```
   form.append('file', Buffer.from(file.data), {
     filename: 'image1.jpg', // ... OR:
     filepath: 'photos/image1.jpg',
     contentType: 'image/jpeg',
     knownLength: 19803
   });

   form.submit('http://example.com/', function(err, res) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log('Done');
   });
   ```

Can you confirm (using something like **WireShark**) what exactly gets sent from React?

Comment: This did not solve the problem. After making these changes [@RequestPart] hitting the API from POSTMAN still worked but from the node server, it failed stating MultipartException just as mentioned above.

Comment: @User_Targaryen added consumes to spring's endpoint and options to React

Comment: wild guess , but i would focus on the pass-thru 'headers' in your node code. Reason - POST stack sometimes may add headers in addition to ones set by your code.  these 'inferred' header vals < compression, lang, chuncking ... > are not always helping the process

Comment: @diginoise: On using `@RequestBody MultipartFile file`, the request came to the JAVA controller, but with `file` as `null`. Why?

Comment: Thanks for the hint about using `options` in `FormData`

Comment: Yes. filename and type were added in options

Comment: @User_Targaryen... sooo, should you therefore accept my answer which added these 1 day before **Prajit's**?  Where is my 200 SOs dude??

Comment: @User_Targaryen, I am facing the same issue. Can u please share how fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I spent a couple of hours on this issue and I didn't expect the issue to be of a value I was passing and not something else as the message was declaring that the key is not exists:
"Required request part 'images' is not present"

At the end I found out that I was passing an array of files and expecting it to work fine as in POSTMAN!
But I had to loop through my array and push the same key every time to be as following..

```
formData.append('images', images[0]);
formData.append('images', images[1]);
```

Here's how my code looks like to accept an array of files

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"), method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/mixed", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<?> addPicture(
      @RequestParam(value="images") MultipartFile[] images) throws IOException {
```